# RewriteRule parameter urls with exceptions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Thanks for your help!
I need to redirect all urls like this:

```
www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/?filter_group=(.*)
www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/page/2/?filter_group=(.*)
```

to

```
www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/?_group=(.*)
www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/?_group=(.*)&_paged=2
```

and all urls like this:

```
www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/subcategoryname/?filter_group=(.*)
www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/subcategoryname/page/2/?filter_group=(.*)
```

to

```
www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/subcategoryname/?_group=(.*)
www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/subcategoryname/?_group=(.*)&_paged=2
```

with two exception:

```
www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/?filter_group=filterone
```

which goes to

```
www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/
```

and

```
www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/subcategoryname/?filter_group=filter-two
```

which goes to

```
www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/subcategoryname/
```

I Tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^filter_group=filterone$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^filter_group=filter-two$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filter_group=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^product-category/(.*)/(.*)?/?$ https://www.example.com/product-category/$1/$2/?_group=%1 [QSD,R=301]
RewriteRule ^product-category/(.*)/page/(.*)/$ https://www.example.com/product-category/$1/?_group=%1&_paged=$2 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^product-category/(.*)/(.*)/page/(.*)/$ https://www.example.com/product-category/$1/$2/?_group=%1&_paged=$3 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filter_group=filterone$
RewriteRule ^ product-category/categoryname/$ https://www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filter_group=filter-two$
RewriteRule ^product-category/categoryname/subcategoryname/$ https://www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/subcategoryname/? [R=301,L]
```

It works except for pagination.
How can I fix?
Thank you!!!

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond: _"REQUEST_URI: The path component of the requested URI, such as "/index.html". **This notably excludes the query string which is available as its own variable named QUERY_STRING.**"_

Comment: Thanks CBroe! Now how can I modify to match also ulrs like these: 

[link] www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/subcategoryname/page/2/?filter_group=filter
[link] www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/page/2/?filter_group=filter

to go to 

[link] www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/subcategoryname/?_group=filter&_paged=2
[link] www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/?_group=filter&_paged=2

Comment: Well start by fixing the mistake I mentioned. You are using the correct variable to access the query string in some of your conditions, and in others ... you aren't.

Comment: Hi, I've already fixed it by replacing {REQUEST_URI} with {QUERY_STRING} and it works, thank you so much. Then I tried to modify it to match also pagination but anything I try does not work. I would like to paste the code but characters are too many and cannot understand how to do it..

Comment: _"I would like to paste the code but characters are too many"_ - what? How HUGE is your .htaccess file then? Anyway, you should be able to show _relevant_ parts that relate to the attempt at handling pagination? Plus example URLs, and where exactly those should be redirected.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to Stack overflow... 
first part of code:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filter_group=(.*)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^filter_group=filterone$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^filter_group=filter-two$
RewriteRule ^product-category/(.*)/(.*)?/?$ https://www.example.com/product-category/$1/$2/?_group=%1 [QSD,R=301]

Comment: second part:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filter_group=filterone$
RewriteRule ^ product-category/categoryname/$ https://www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filter_group=filter-two$
RewriteRule ^product-category/categoryname/subcategoryname/$ https://www.example.com/product-category/categoryname/subcategoryname/? [R=301,L]

Comment: Add that into the question please, properly formatted - this is hard to read in comments. And add example URLs, please - cause so far, I can't even see where the "pagination" part is supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, I've modified the question as you suggested

Comment: `RewriteRule ^product-category/([^/]+)(/page/([0-9]+))?/?$ https://www.example.com/product-category/$1/?_group=%1&page=$3 [R=301]` should work for both the URL with and without `page/XY` in it - if you can live with the `page` parameter being _set_, but with an empty value. (If you need it to not be set at all, then it would make more sense to handle the pagination URLs separately.)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. It works only for urls without `/subcategoryname/`. I need to handle the pagination URLs separately because if `page` isn't in the url it should not be set.